# Is there a way to understand why java.util.concurrent.Future is failed to cancel?

Tags: java, scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

I ran an application which schedule to make some job every X time, for this mission I used `ScheduledExecutorService` and `java.util.concurrent.Future`. 
Everything work well but I want to troubleshoting possible issues in the future and for that I want to log the reason for failure.

Example:

```
private  ScheduledExecutorService executeScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private   ScheduledFuture doSomthing = executeScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {DO SOMETHING} , 1000, 1000, MILLISECONDS);
if(doSomthing.cancel(!true)){
    logger.warn("WHY FAILED");
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but what is your question?

Comment: The question is if there is a way to get from doSomthing why it failed or if there is another interface which similar to `java.util.concurrent.Future` which give this information

Comment: I still don't understand it. Do you want to log any encountered exception while executing the schedule job? Or do you want to be able to cancel it and log the reason?

Comment: When the cancel failed I want to get the reason why it failed (I can't guess it, it should return some exception )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.​util.​concurrent.​Future`
.cancel() will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the `.cancel(true/false)` parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.

in case that you use (true) and your thread/{DO SOMTHING} get interrupted you can see that by calling
doSomthing.get()
.It throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException;
so you should wrap it with try/catch.

note that .get() locks and return only a throwable. but in your case it will be obvious that the reason will be InterruptedException,
OR, maybe you didn't want to use that .cancel in the first place?

if you try to catch a general running exception you must wrap one big try/catch inside you thread run method or just here:
`{DO SOMETHING}`